# «С квартиры» или «из квартиры»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: *выселение **из** квартиры* или *выселение **с** квартиры*, если она съемная (и в случае собственной)?

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

И по холодку фирсовской интонации Векшин понял, что его **выселяют с квартиры** для других жильцов (Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Часть 3 (1927, 1959)).

В частности, наниматель и проживающие с ним члены семьи **подлежат выселению из квартиры**, занимаемой по договору социального найма, в случае, если они в течение шести месяцев не оплачивали жильё (Игорь Пылаев. Политический капремонт (2003) // «Еженедельный журнал», 24.03.2003).

Если человек живет на съемной квартире — предлог НА. А если выселяют — С или ИЗ?

Comment: Если человек живет на съемной квартире - предлог НА — думаю, предлог В в этом выражении не только допустим, но и употребляется не намного реже.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, что как минимум в интересах хорошего стиля предлог должен *сочетаться с приставкой* глагола: **вы**ехать или быть **вы**селенным **из** квартиры, **с**ъехать **с** квартиры, **пере**езжать **с** квартиры **на** квартиру (с места на место), либо **из** квартиры **в** квартиру и т. д. Если бегло оценить статистику, то сочетаний типа "**вы**селен **с** квартиры" в "Корпусе" находится по *одному* случаю на вариант формы глагола "выселить", в то время как всего случаев предложной формы "**с квартиры**" более двух сотен (227 документов и 295 вхождений). По такой же причине неестественным выглядит сочетание "*вселиться на квартиру*", съёмная она или нет.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **выселить из квартиры (своей или съемной).** Это точное грамматическое сочетание при любом статусе квартиры.

Но вот задается вопрос: **В каких случаях хозяин не может выгнать (выселить) со съемной квартиры раньше оговоренного периода времени?**

В этом случае имеется в виду лишить **именно съемного жилья**, выселить с территории съемного жилья (**обобщенный вариант**), и поэтому здесь **допускается предлог С в разговорном стиле.**

Из словаря:

ВЫСЕЛИТЬ, св. кого. Заставить покинуть место своего жительства, обитания; переселить куда-л. **В. жильцов из квартиры**. В. на Север. В. в соседнюю область.

В Грамматике-80 указано, что **приставка глагола должна быть семантически соотнесена с предлогом:**

**ВЫ/ИЗ**: выйти из дома, вырезать из бумаги, выпустить из рук.

**С/С:** сбежать с горы, сбросить с крыши, сдвинуть с места.

**Если нет соответствия,** то это неточная грамматика, и такие варианты обычно относятся к разговорному  стилю.

Кстати, у Леонова вся фраза странная: выселяют с квартиры, выселяют  для других жильцов.

Comment: Какое-то странное правило. У меня язык не поворачивается сказать "выселить из территории", "вынести из поля боя", "вырастить из каждого гектара" и мн. др.

Comment: А в этих примерах нет альтернативных сочетаний предлога направления с существительным - нет и проблемы выбора.

Comment: @Alex_ander Ага, я, наверное, неправильно понял выражение "семантически соотнесена". Оно включает в себя рассмотрение "альтернативных сочетаний предлога направления с существительным"? Хорошо, я поищу Грамматику-80 и попытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: @Alex_ander Нет, не могу понять. Разве есть альтернативные сочетания предлога направления с существительным в выражениях "сбросить с крыши, сдвинуть с места и т.п.". А в правиле эти выражения даны в качестве примеров. Думаю, Вы ошибаетесь в трактовке этого правила. Загвоздка в чём-то другом.

Comment: @grizzly  Думаю, что здесь надо учитывать сложные связи: вырастить из ребенка личность и вырастить урожай  в количестве 10 центнеров с каждого гектара; вынести раненого товарища из боя и выносить раненых с поля боя.

Comment: @ grizzly Я не правило трактую, а наш случай отделяю от тех, где альтернатив "нахождения" нет (на/с территории). У нас возможны варианты пар предлогов направления - в зависимости от того, имеется ли в виду буквальное нахождение внутри квартиры или она рассматривается как более абстрактное местонахождение.

Answer (score 3):

Считаю, что грамотно говорить так:
**выселить** (выселять, выселение) **из** **квартиры**, из дома, из скворечника.

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) пишет:
**выселя́ть**
Участники ситуации, описываемой с помощью *выселять*: (1) субъект (им. п.), (2) объект (вин. п.), (3) исходное место (из + род. п.).

Как **выселить** (кого? В. п.) **дебошира** (из чего? Р. п.) **из квартиры** на законных основаниях?

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):
ВЫСЕЛЕНИЕ, -я; ср. к *Выселить - выселять* и *Выселиться - выселяться.*
**Массовое выселение птиц из гнездовий.**

*И все-таки Артема настораживала поспешность, с которой старик был выселен из квартиры* (П. Астахов. Квартира).

*Но постепенно кукушка «выселила» петуха из механического «курятника»* (о появлении часов с кукушкой).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, правильно "выселить из квартиры", но в сочетании с "выселить/съехать" и "съемной" - как минимум возможно "с квартиры". **Выселить со съемной квартиры**. Тут вот какая штука. Жить можно "в квартире", а можно и "на квартире". У сочетаний несколько разный смысл. Мне сейчас трудно привести какое-то авторитетное обоснование, но по моим представлением первое означает скорее физическое пребывание, второе - юридическое.

При этом в русском языке предлоги НА и В (в значении "где") соответствуют С и ИЗ (откуда) соответственно. Это весьма строго и последовательно. "Выселение" да еще из "съемной" это, как правило, акт юридический. Отсюда и мое понимание варианта *"со съемной квартиры"*.

Вот когда судебные приставы физически придут пожитки ваши выносить - вас будут выселять **из** квартиры. Правда, тогда она уже не будет называться "съемной".

Короче, похоже, тут есть какая-то тонкость, не отмеченная напрямую в словарях.